# SDL_Image library crashes programs or makes them misbehave

Tags: c++, sdl

I have an sdl2 program which works fine on my machine(win xp 32bit). When i send it to my friend (win 10 64bit), the program displays the SetRenderDrawColor and crashes after a few seconds.
This program uses SDL2 and SDL2_Image.

I then copied a barebones sdl2 program from a website.
And it works on both of our computers.

I then modified the program to use IMG_Load from the SDL_Image library, which again, works fine on my end, but this time, doesn't crash, but instead just displays the set RenderDrawColor and but not the loaded image and closes after the SDL_Delay finishes on my friends computer.

The compile command that I used is:

```
g++ main.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL_Image -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o main.exe
```

Also while I'm at it, I'll say that no sdl2 program works on my win7 nor my win xp computers if I don't have the #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED. However no tutorial that I ever came across said that I need to use such a thing.

Any help?

Edit: Posting barebone program code

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_Image.h>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    int posX = 100;
    int posY = 200;
    int sizeX = 300;
    int sizeY = 400;
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Event event;

    // Initialize SDL
    // ==========================================================
    if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) != 0 )
    {
        // Something failed, print error and exit.
        std::cout << " Failed to initialize SDL : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Initialize SDL_Image
    int flags = IMG_INIT_JPG|IMG_INIT_PNG;
    int initted = IMG_Init(flags);

    if((initted&flags) != flags)
    {
      printf("IMG_Init: Failed to init required jpg and png support!\n");
      printf("IMG_Init: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
    }

    // Create and init the window
    // ==========================================================
    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "test", posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY, 0 );

    if ( window == nullptr )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window : " << SDL_GetError();
        return -1;
    }

    // Create and init the renderer
    // ==========================================================
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );

    if ( renderer == nullptr )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create renderer : " << SDL_GetError();
        return -1;
    }

    // Render something
    // ==========================================================    
    // Load image
    SDL_Surface* loader = IMG_Load("background.jpg");
    SDL_Texture* sprite = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loader);

    if(loader == NULL)
    {
       std::cout << "Loader failed!" << std::endl << std::endl;
       IMG_GetError();
    }
    // Set size of renderer to the same as window
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize( renderer, sizeX, sizeY );

    // Set color of renderer to red
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255 );

    // Clear the window and make it all red
    SDL_RenderClear( renderer );

    // Draw image
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, sprite, 0, 0);

    // Render the changes above ( which up until now had just happened behind the scenes )
    SDL_RenderPresent( renderer);

    // Pause program so that the window doesn't disappear at once.

    while(true)
    {
      SDL_PollEvent(&event);

      if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) return 0;

      SDL_Delay( 10 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add your code so we can be sure there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I will when I'll be back at home, however I highly doubt that it's a code issue but more of a dependancy/incompatability one since it works fine on my end.

Comment: Alright. Next question: Did you check return value of IMG_Init?

Comment: Did you compile sdl into static libraries using the same compiler?

Comment: IMG_Init doesn't show any errors with the above code on my or my friends computers.

Comment: maybe a difference in the current working directory of the program?  Not sure.  You're not checking error codes, so it's really not clear where the real error is coming from vs when you're seeing it because you kept going long after an error occurred and was reported.

Comment: @Habitate as was already said, you need to check return value of `IMG_Load` (and, if NULL, inspect `IMG_GetError`). Other thing is your event handling being wrong - return value of `SDL_PollEvent` have to be utilised or you're processing a garbage data. As for `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED`, it is usually not a good idea unless you sure what you're doing, and I believe is addressed by FAQ - you need to link with `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`, in that order (add `SDL2_image` at the tail if you need it).

Comment: @keltar, thanks for the info about `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED`, I managed to fix it, then I added error checking for the code, which then, on my friends computer, complained about `libpng16-16.dll` being missing, so I copied over the dll from my MingGW installation and included it in the zip for my friend. And so the result is this error: `The procedure entry point inflateValidate could not be located in the dynamic link library pwd\libpng16-16.dll` as a pop-up message.

Comment: You seem to have copied a wrong `libpng16-16.dll`. Use the one that comes with SDL2_image.

Comment: Im 100% certain that I copied the dll from the sdl_image folder when I downloaded it. Now I also tried to give him the 64bit .dll which produces the following: `IMG_Init: Failed to init required jpg and png support!
IMG_Init: Failed loading libpng16-16.dll: ├É`. Maybe I should download the runtime libraries instead of the development ones and gives those to him?

Comment: @Habitate libpng depends on zlib, inflate/deflate are surely from there. SDL_image binary distro have required zlib.

Comment: @keltar, Thank you, your solution of adding zlib solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding `libpng16-16.dll and zlib1.dll` from the MingGW installation into the distributed folder.

If anyone else has this issue, the total of .dlls that were needed for this to work were:

`SDL2.dll | SDL2_Image.dll | libwinpthread-1.dll | libpng16-16.dll| zlib1.dll`.